# Laravel RegisterController функция validtor

Tags: laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста что за функция validator находится в RegisterController. Документацию читаю отсюда и вопрос, судя по ней как раз таки есть куча способов отвалидировать даннные например инъектить в функцию параметр Request и работать с ним. А тут мало того какая-то непонятная функция нигде не описанная, не переопределенная, так еще и не понятно где сие чудо вызывается. А ведь без этой функции не работает регистрация. Что в общем происходит?... Мне кажется или yii2 в это плане интуитивно понятный. На лару только начал переходить, до этого работал с phalcon и yii2... Поэтому пока есть как вы видите трудности в понимании общей концепции лары...

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Register Controller
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
  | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
  | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
  |
  */

  use RegistersUsers;

  /**
   * Where to redirect users after registration.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $redirectTo = '/home';

  /**
   * Create a new controller instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('guest');
  }

  /**
   * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
   *
   * @param  array $data
   * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
   */
  protected function validator(array $data)
  {
    return Validator::make($data, [
      'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
      'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
  }

  /**
   * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
   *
   * @param  array $data
   * @return \App\User
   */
  protected function create(array $data)
  {
    return User::create([
      'name' => $data['name'],
      'email' => $data['email'],
      'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Прежде чем делать выводы, нужно посмотреть на класс, который наследуется и на трейты класса. В данном случае, на `RegistersUsers`.

Comment: Мда точно был не внимателен. Но все равно, лучше бы они вынесли его в интерфейс и реализовали бы его в контроллере так было бы понятней. Наверно. В любом случае спасибо ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> так еще и не понятно где сие чудо вызывается

Вызывается вот тут: `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php` (`use RegistersUsers;` в приведённом фрагменте кода), в методе `register`, который обрабатывает запрос с данными юзера при попытке зарегистрироваться.

Comment: А функция registered которая находится в том же трейте, наужна для кастамной регистрации? Или как?

Comment: @JohnBrowning, да, судя по тому, что функция пустая — вы можете переопределить её в коде вашего контроллера